# Vagrant Uninitialized Constant MixinSyncedFolders

Tags: windows, vagrant, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-windows

Trying to vagrant up I get this error

```
uninitialized constant Vagrant::Action::Builtin::MixinSyncedFolders
```

vagrant plugin list

```
vagrant-berkshelf (4.0.3)
vagrant-share (1.1.3, system)
vagrant-windows (1.6.0)
```

vagrant -v

```
Vagrant 1.7.2
```

My Box is windows server 2012, Virtualbox version 4.3.20 with matching guest additions installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall the plugin `vagrant-windows` which is no longer needed in vagrant 1.6+.

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-windows
```